# Withdrawn question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I have just noticed that [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/307912/9924), which I have found quite exciting (and so have at least 14 other users who have voted for it) has been withdrawn by the OP. Is there any way to figure out the reason for that?

Comment: I do not have the rights to see into this, but generally I do not like when well-recieved questions get deleted. This should be usually undone. Unless there is something here, but then you should be able to see that.

Comment: It's now undeleted.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: well, I was one those voting to undelete it, but I still wonder what was the reason for deleting it...

Comment: I think all you can do is ask. The site mods have no behind-the-scenes insight here.

Comment: @ToddTrimble This problem has imposed by someone to me for doing research on it. Today he told me that he did not allowed me to present the problem to others. So I deleted the question and informed him. Sorry for this mistake, but I ask the moderators to agree with my decision.

Comment: @Mostafa Let me take a look. In general we discourage self-deletions, but there can be extenuating circumstances. Please check very carefully next time -- thanks.

Comment: Okay, I've deleted it.  Please know that I am loath to delete *especially* those questions that have already received upvoted answers. Luckily it had not been answered yet.

Comment: @Mostafa In case you aren't aware of it, this problem has appeared in print before. Yuster has a paper on it and attributes it to Caro https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6f3b/d8ad6ece6cc594bbe78174d7f94918ad9653.pdf In particular Alon and Lovasz and other mathematicians from that circle have looked at this problem. It still remains open, and maybe it hasn't had much visibility, but I though of letting you know that it has a small history.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi Thanks for the references. I didn't find any reference myself.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: The problem considered by Yuster (following Alon et al) is actually subtly different: he seeks a vector $v\in\mathbb F_p^n$ such that all coordinates of $Av$ are non-zero, *and* all coordinates of $v$ are in $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Mostafa: Please, see my previous comment.

Comment: I think moderators should ask the user (hoping there is a way) for reason to delete the question before reversing that delete done by user... I think to undelete with out inquiring about the reason seems to be not a good idea.. This does not mean I think well received question can be  deleted...

Comment: @Seva problem 1.2 in that paper is exactly Mostafa's problem.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: not exactly, as far as I can see. Mostafa wants $x\in\mathbb F_p^n$ such that $Ax$ has all its entries distinct from $0$, Yuster wants this $x$ to reside in $\{0,1\}^n\subset\mathbb F_p^n$. (In fact, $x$ is the indicator vector of a $p$-NZDS.) Agreed?

Comment: @Seva His language is a bit confusing. After defining $p-$NZDS in the first paragraph, he then redefines them in the general case of an arbitrary function $d$, which I interpreted as not necessarily $0,1$ valued. Theorem 1.1 answers Mostafa's first question which was answered by David here, and it seemed natural that problem 1.2 is to be interpreted in the general sense of a $p-$NZDF in the terminology he uses, meaning arbitrary symmetric $\{0,1\}$ matrix with 1's on diagonal, and arbitrary function $d:G\to \mathbb F_p$.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: Well, not sure about this interpretation; see also http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/a_nowhere_zero_point_in_a_linear_mapping

Comment: @Seva In the beginning of page 2, in the general case he says "The subset of vertices with $d(v)\neq 0$ is the $p$-NZDS in this case". What convinces me is 1) the mention of Sutner's paper and 2) Prop 1.1 and the remarks after it, saying that Alon-Lovasz's example is not a 0,1 matrix. So it is natural that the follow up question is "can we construct such a 0,1 matrix?". If we could, we would have a counterexample, a graph with no $p$-NZDS in the general sense above.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi To add to my previous comment. At the end of page 2, Yuster writes: "The first nontrivial family of graphs for which the answer to Problem 1.2 has been shown true is the family of trees." If we interpret Problem 1.2 your way, then Problem 1.2 is trivial for the trees: take a leaf away, find an appropriate vector $x\in\mathbb F_p^{n-1}$ for the resulting graph, and you will always be able to append a coordinate to it for the leaf that has been taken away to keep the property in question.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: one final "disclaimer". Yuster and myself are, essentially, in the same department, and I hope to talk to him about this problem soon (but maybe not next week as I will be travelling).

Comment: @Seva I feel bad for spamming the comments here, I was going to add this to the original question, and I wish it was still up, for visibility if anything, since I really liked the question. I look forward to hearing if Yuster knows of any updates on the problem!

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: addressing your last comment: I agree that he is speaking about zero-one matrices, but I believe he also speaks about nowhere-zero input vectors, while Mostafa does not insist theinput  vector to be nowhere-zero.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik It was ordinary users who undeleted the question. Not site moderators.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: Quoting from an e-mail message I received from Yuster, *Well, Zaimi is right that the problem 1.2 is for any vector $x$ (not just a 0-1 vector) see the definition in line 4 of Page 2. 

But you are right that since I quote Caro and Jacobson, then the special case where we require 0-1 is what they looked at in that paper. Also, my proof uses only 0-1 in the vector. 

In any case, as far as I know, even the less restrictive version (where you allow $x$ to be arbitrary) is open.*

Comment: @Seva Thank you for all this (and for the link to Devos's problem in openproblemgarden as well)!

Comment: @ToddTrimble I thought it is only moderators who can do that... my comment can be directed towards who have un deleted the question... who ever has done that could have asked... that is what I mean..

Comment: The question needs to be undeleted. The comments being longer than the question and stating several partial results and proofs, it should be clear that at this point the question no longer belongs just to the author. Compare it with the case of a question that has received an upvoted answer.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I suggest that another user ask this question in MO and add a summery of relevant material obtained so far.

Answer (score 9):

Mostafa's comment above:

> This problem has imposed by someone to me for doing research on it. Today he told me that he did not allow me to present the problem to others. So I deleted the question and informed him. Sorry for this mistake, but I ask the moderators to agree with my decision.